# How to factor $16x^2-y^2+8y-16$ so I get $(4x+y-4)(4x-y+4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, circles, factoring

I tried completing the square, making it equal to zero, and trying to think of it as a circle, but I still can't prove that these two are equivalent. I tried to factor this in Wolfram Alpha, and it spits out that answer. But I don't know how else to get to it.

Comment: the quadratic form part $16 x^2 - y^2$ is nondegenerate, Hessian determinant nonzero. This means that the center of the conic section occurs where the gradient is zero, here both $32x = 0$ and $-2y+8 = 0.$

Comment: The point is that it is *not* a circle. First, it would be a hyperbola. Second, the constant term goes away when you complete the square, so instead of $(4x)^2 - (y+4)^2 = 1$, say, you have $(4x)^2-(y+4)^2 = 0$, which is in fact a union of two lines (the asymptotes of the hyperbolas). Note that, as someone already wrote in an answer, this factors as a difference of squares and gives you what you had in the title.

Comment: Sorry, could you dumb it down for me?

Comment: Whoj, look at some of the many questions tagged conic sections, let us see what happens when I put the url here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conic-sections

Comment: @TedShifrin we get a million conic section questions here, i think this student is coming at this from some other direction, I guess contest. The attempt to factor is a bit unusual.

Comment: @Will, I went there because the OP said “trying to think of it as a circle.” I think your answer is at way too advanced a level, but ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$16x^2-y^2+8y-16 =16x^2-(y^2-8y+16)=(4x)^2-(y-4)^2$$

then recall that

$$A^2-B^2=(A+B)(A-B)$$

Comment: I already did that but how does (4x-0)(4x+0)-(y-4)(y-4) get me to (4x+y-4)(4x-y+4)

Comment: @WhojJeong From here $(4x)^2-(y-4)^2$ with $A=4x$ and $B=y-4$ we have $(4x)^2-(y-4)^2=(4x+y-4)(4x-y+4)$.

Comment: Thanks makes so much sense! Thank You!

Comment: @WhojJeong You are welcome! Since you ar enew here recall that you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @WhojJeong also, my email is in my profile, if you wish to send me money that would be appreciated

Comment: @WillJagy No money are not allowed :P! But accept an answer is an answer among the given is how it works there. Refer also to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88535/389429

Comment: I know. Years ago, I remember a user on Math Overflow saying something similar. His phrasing was interesting (and correct): he said an acceptance was the "coin of the realm"

Comment: @WillJagy Many new user here ask for answers and never accept them, I think it is a good habit in these cases give  a remainder about that, in particular for new users.

Answer (score 1):

I f you want to be systematic, add in a variable $z$ to make this homogeneous,
$$ 16 x^2 - y^2 - 16 z^2 + 8 y  z  $$
with result (below)
$$ 16 x^2 - y^2 - 16 z^2 + 8 y  z = 16 x^2 - (y-4z)^2 = (4x+y-4z)(4x-y+4z)  $$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 &  - 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 &  - 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 &  - 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 &  - 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Fancy Matrices you got there!

Answer (score 0):

$$16x^2-y^2+8y-16=16x^2-(y-4)^2=(4x-(y-4))(4x+(y-4))$$

At the last step I used $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, in which $a= 4x$ and $b=y-4$.